# How to run a custom set of programs in a specific workspace?

Tags: scripts, customization, workspaces, desktop-environments, default-programs

I use several workspaces in order to have different context for different works. Therefore, I run the same set of applications in the same workspace repeatedly. And also I run the same application in each set of applications, so setting the default workspace where each application should run doesn't work for this purpose.

For instance:

- Workspace1: 1 terminal + 2 tabs
  opened in Chrome + a document opened
  with PDF Viewer
- Workspace2: 3
  terminals + 4 tabs opened in Chrome +
  1 tab opened in Firefox + Eclipse

So, is there any way to have a script or something like set_workspace1.sh that once run open all the desired programs in a specific workspace?

BTW, I'm running 11.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command or script to open specific programs to different virtual desktops](http://askubuntu.com/questions/63763/command-or-script-to-open-specific-programs-to-different-virtual-desktops)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that there's such a function for the standard window manager.

But Devil's Pie can do what you want.

http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie/

Quote from Devil's Pie website: *"Devil's Pie can be configured to detect windows as they are created, and match the window to a set of rules. If the window matches the rules, it can perform a series of actions on that window. For example, I can make all windows created by X-Chat appear on all workspaces, and the main Gkrellm1 window does not appear in the pager or task list."*

I hope this helped you,

Daniel

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel, but I don't think that Devil's Pie can do the work.
I think that I simply (hopefully) need to create some customized scripts to run each program and positionate it in the correct workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking workspaces are referred to as `viewports` , a specific section of the extended desktop, with specific coordinates, for instance `0, 0` is the viewport 1 and `1366, 0` would be the one immediately to the right.

It should be noted that [CompizConfig Settings Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/) has an option for "fixed" opening of a window  on specific workspace, but  one can create a script like you've mentioned. Here's my example.

```
#!/bin/bash
get_viewport()
{
  xprop -root -notype _NET_DESKTOP_VIEWPORT | awk '{print $3,$4}' 
}

spawn_viewport_1()
{
  nohup gnome-terminal 2>&1   > /dev/null  &
  nohup chromium-browser 2>&1 > /dev/null  &
}

spawn_viewport_2()
{
 nohup xterm 2>&1 > /dev/null  &
  nohup firefox 2>&1 > /dev/null  &
}

main()
{
  case $(get_viewport) in
   "0, 0") spawn_viewport_1  ;; # note , single space in "0, 0" is important
   "1366, 0") spawn_viewport_2    ;;
  esac
}

main
```

Essentially what is happening is that I've got two functions, each for specific viewport. I also have a function that checks what viewport I am currently on. If I am currently on viewport 1 (coordinates 0,0) it will spawn one set of apps. If I am on viewport 2 (coordinates 1366,0), we will have different set of apps spawned.