# How can I tell what workspace I am in with Unity?

Tags: unity, workspaces

Long time user of Ubuntu struggling to use Unity here....

I am running Unity 2D and can click on the workspace launcher icon to switch to a different workspace. However if I just walk up to a system, how can I tell by looking what workspace I am on?

Is the launcher icon supposed to change when you change workspace?  Is there an indicator applet for this I can install?  I am used to the old Gnome workspace switcher in the middle of the top panel!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### 13.04

This functionality is now inbuilt within 13.04 and later - the launcher workspace icon shows which workspace you are currently on:

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

### 12.10 and previous

[image]

#### 10.04/10.10/11.04/11.10

To do this, first install the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:geod/ppa-geod
```

Update and install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-workspaces
```

#### 12.04 onwards

The PPA author does not have a preprepared package for 12.04 and later.  However, you can download the same deb-package used in 11.10 and install that.

Download the [v0.6.2.2 deb package](http://ppa.launchpad.net/geod/ppa-geod/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator-workspaces/indicator-workspaces_0.6.2.2_all.deb)

Install the prerequisite:

```
sudo apt-get install python-wnck
```

#### how to start

Finally add `indicator-workspaces` to your startup-applications (search in Dash for this) if the installation hasn't already added this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help on this.  Ridiculous this isn't built in!

Comment: nitpicking: we nowadays have 1 workspace and the 4 'parts' are viewports. http://askubuntu.com/questions/44102/what-is-a-viewport-what-about-a-workspace

Comment: In 12.10 with Unity the auto-start does not work, but the proggie can be started from the command line 'indicator-workspace', after which it works fine and interacts well with the workspace selector in the Launcher bar. Unfortunately it is not possible to name the workspaces.

Comment: This also fails if you have compiz cube rotate on or other special effects.

Comment: Working on 14.04 (installed the deb package)!

Answer (score 6):

**Ubunutu 14.10** (Based off of fossfreedom's answer, sorry I need more rep to comment)

1. `sudo apt-get install python-wnck`
2. `sudo apt-get install python-appindicator`
3. `wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/geod/ppa-geod/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator-workspaces/indicator-workspaces_0.6.2.2_all.deb`
4. `sudo dpkg -i ./indicator-workspaces_0.6.2.2_all.deb`
5. `indicator-workspaces & disown`
6. (Add to startup as fossfreedom mentions above)

Comment: Why is this even needed? Because of Unity2D? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with regular Unity and the workspace indicator shows on my launcher bar with no further action required, once I've enabled workspaces (Settings->Appearance->Behavior).

Comment: Yeah I had that on my launcher but it didn't work for my use case.  It displayed 2x2 but I use 1x5.  The [simple number display](https://i.imgur.com/Xzih3UD.png) works much better for me.

Comment: 5 workspaces, wow! You must be a master multitasker. :)

Comment: Yeah I don't often use all 5 extensively, but when I need them it's really helpful :P  I made the convention of 5 a long time ago when I think I was using compiz's "cube".  I found the uneven number easier to recall spatially, and stuck with it through different systems. I'll I often 'backburner' my entire work-space when urgent items come up, and sometimes those emergencies will layer one on top of another.

Answer (score 5):

If you do download the latest version from http://ppa.launchpad.net/geod/ppa-geod/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator-workspaces/ make sure you grab the required wnck libs/bindings in synaptic or the software center. Otherwise this indicator will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's Unity desktop uses viewports , not workspaces, which is a coordinate-based system.

To know current viewport , you can bind the following set of commands (or place them into a script and bind that ) to a keyboard shortcut:

```
xprop -root -notype _NET_DESKTOP_VIEWPORT  | awk -F '=' '{ print "Current Viewport:"$2  }' | xargs -I {} notify-send {}
```

[image]

That way you can invoke an on-screen notification to report where are you on the grid right now.

Personally, because I spend 99% of time between firefox and terminal, I've all those commands , set into a function in my `.bashrc`

```
get_viewport()
{
  xprop -root -notype _NET_DESKTOP_VIEWPORT  | \
      awk -F '=' '{ print "Current Viewport:"$2  }' | \
      xargs -I {} notify-send {}
}
```