# See workspace name in taskbar

Tags: workspaces, taskbar

In 11.10 I could set preferences and apply names to the different workspaces. In 12.10 I installed CompizConfig Setttings Manager and enabled workspace naming, and I can get the names to show up when switching to a workspace, but in 11.10 the name of the current workspace showed up in the bottom right-hand corner, i.e. in the taskbar.

Is there a setting that will add the name of the workspace to the taskbar, or some other place, so that I can easily see which workspace I'm in?

BTW - I've answered my own question, I just needed to use metacity instead of compiz.

Comment: These are all of the options for all the current releases and 13.04: http://askubuntu.com/questions/77160/how-can-i-tell-what-workspace-i-am-in-with-unity

Comment: Uh...that doesn't work. I installed indicator-workspaces and, oddly enough, when it is running and I click on it I can see the list of workspace (viewport) names I defined in 11.10 (I set up slightly different ones in 12.10). But if I select any of them, I end up some place odd and have to hit something (I think it's Alt-F2) to get back. But when I use the keyboard shortcuts to go to other viewports the indicator never updates.

Comment: I take that back...or rather, let me qualify that: It does seem to work fine if I select "Ubuntu" rather than "Gnome Classic", but I prefer/need Gnome classic...

Comment: Alright, so in wandering about, searching to figure out why indicator-workspaces found my old workspace names, I saw that it came from metacity. So I started up metacity to replace compiz, and viola! it works like it used to...