# How to move Workspace switcher tab to upper right corner?

Tags: unity

I want to move "WorkSpace Switcher Tab" to left of "Wifi settings tab" in upper right corner.
[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I have found an answer (http://askubuntu.com/a/603676/456951) not exactly answer to this question but achieves same goal of showing workspace in upper right corner.

Comment: also removed "workspace switcher tab" using this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/286344/456951 [P.S.: works also in ubuntu 14.04]