# Show current desktop (workspace) in taskbar

Tags: unity, compiz, workspaces, multiple-desktops

I currently use Compiz Desktop Wall to move between workspaces, but occasionally I lose my orientation when something automatically moves me to another workspace or I come back to my computer after leaving.  Is it possible to label workspaces so that the current workspace I'm in shows somewhere on the taskbar?  Either with text or an icon showing where on the wall I'm at would be great.  Does something like this exist?

Comment: Most desktops have a workspace selector that can be added to the taskbar, unfortunately I am unfamiliar with your desktop and can not give more detail.

Comment: What desktop are you running?

Comment: Desktop is Unity

Answer (score 0):

Open `CompizConfig Settings Manager` and click on the `Workspace Naming` tile. You can name your workspaces here.

[image]

You can also Google "Ubuntu workspace indicator". I found this: [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available/38058#38058). I hasn't been updated for a while, so it may not work, but it's an indication of what may be available. Also see [How can I tell what workspace I am in with Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77160/how-can-i-tell-what-workspace-i-am-in-with-unity/77225#77225).

Also remember that 17.10 will use GNOME, instead of Unity, and it has a built-in workspaces extension.

**Update**:

Download indicator-workspaces at http://ppa.launchpad.net/geod/ppa-geod/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator-workspaces/indicator-workspaces_0.6.4_all.deb.

You may need to install these:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-wnck
sudo apt-get install python-appindicator
sudo dpkg -i ./indicator-workspaces_0.6.4_all.deb
```

Comment: I don't seem to have `Workspace Naming` available in my Compiz Settings Manager.  I'm on 16.04 if that matters.

Comment: I installed the addons to get Workspace Naming working but it wasn't quite what I'm looking for.  I tried installing `indicator-workspaces` but it doesn't seem to be hosted anymore :(

Comment: @GameKyuubi get it at http://ppa.launchpad.net/geod/ppa-geod/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator-workspaces/indicator-workspaces_0.6.4_all.deb

Comment: @GameKyuubi Please see the update to my answer, and please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!