# Different Launchers for Different Workspaces?

Tags: launcher

I want to have Different Sidebar Launchers for Different Workspaces, eg Internet Apps in first, Entertainment apps launchers in Second, Games apps launchers in third etc How can i do it?

Comment: Anyone who is wondering how to do it on Ubuntu 17 or 18: [here is an answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992558/how-can-i-configure-the-ubuntu-dock-to-show-windows-only-from-the-current-worksp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took a few years, but now you can have a launcher with diffent pinned applications in different workspaces with [Unity LauncherSwitcher](https://launchpad.net/lswitcher). (Thanks to [webupd8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/04/organize-your-unity-launcher-based-on.html) for making me aware of it.)

Run these commands to install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vlijm/lswitcher
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lswitcher
```

Answer (score 3):

Unity does not have 4 launchers so you can not have different launchers for different  viewports (yes I used viewports, not workspaces).

`Unity Workspaces Switcher` uses Compiz version of [viewports](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44102/what-is-a-viewport-what-about-a-workspace) so basically you have a launcher that activates a split screen based on the vertical and horizontal amount of  viewports. This is not the same as workspaces in Gnome 2. This is actually 1 workspace with 1,2,4 or more viewports.

Comment: ... I think Unity 5.2 and the multi-monitor support may have launchers per workspace/monitor? (http://ubuntumanual.org/posts/591/unity-5-2-hits-the-road-now-with-multi-monitor-support)

Comment: That's more likely to be the same icons in a launcher on all monitors. If (when?) I find new info on this I'll update it :+