# How can I configure the Ubuntu Dock to show windows only from the current workspace?

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, ubuntu-dock

I would like my Dock to show only the windows of the current workspace. Especially in the little preview window.
I find it very confusing to jump around workspaces when trying to find the right window.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Open Terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-workspaces true
```

Comment: This might work for the dash-to-dock GNOME extension, but does not work on the default dock on Pop!_OS 20.04, presumably the same as on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @raisinrising Works fine with the default Ubuntu Dock as confirmed by many others repeatedly. This is because the default Ubuntu Dock is a fork of the Dash to Dock extension and thus they share many `dconf`/`gsettings` schemata and keys. Anyway, Pop OS is not supported here, consider asking a question at [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Oh I see. Very well then. :) I received the error `No such schema “org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock”` on Pop OS but if it works on Ubuntu itself, I agree with you.

Comment: @raisinrising I never used Pop OS, but as I understand from [their support site](https://support.system76.com/articles/dash-to-dock/), Pop OS doesn't come with *any* dock pre-installed. The support-page says: "*the dock is only visible when the Activities menu is open*", but that is actually the [GNOME dash](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-introduction.html.en), a feature of GNOME Shell, not really a dock per se. And the webpage asks to install Dash to Dock manually to get a fully-fledged dock. So it turns out, in this context, Ubuntu and Pop OS behave quite differently.

Comment: OMG! Worked instantly!

Comment: `isolate-workspaces` should be the default, as people like me use workspaces precisely to isolate bundles of things from each other. Or maybe I'm just missing why other folks may prefer the existing default behaviour (everything shown in the dock, from all workspaces)

Comment: Would be nice to be able to specify which apps should be shared and which ones should be isolated.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Dash to Dock extension, you can click on *Isolate Workspaces* to show the apps running in only the specific workspace.

You can find this option in the Dash to Dock settings:

1. Go to the Extensions app on your Ubuntu 20.04.
2. Click on the settings button in front of Dash to Dock.
3. Then go to *Launchers* tab and enable *Isolate Workspaces*.

Here is a screenshot of the Dash to Dock *Launchers* tab:

[image: Dash to Dock Launchers tab]

Answer (score 2):

You may use the '*Workspace Isolated Dash*' GNOME extension.

Here you can see more information about this extension, and also install it: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/887/workspace-isolated-dash/

Comment: You do this through just a command, no need to install any extension.