# How can I configure `Alt-Tab` to show only windows from the current workspace?

Tags: gnome, 17.10

When switching windows using `Alt-Tab`, I would like to see only windows from the current workspace.

Is there a way to configure that?

Relates to  [How can I configure the Ubuntu Dock to show only windows from the current workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992558/how-can-i-configure-the-ubuntu-dock-to-show-only-windows-from-the-current-worksp)