# Workspace indicator on applications preview Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, workspaces, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

There is any solution (gnome extension, soft, ...) to indicate the actual workspace of each application windows with Ubuntu 17.10 and GNOME Shell 3.26.2.

For example, in the picture below, I just want to know in which workspace each Firefox window is located.

[image: Multiple firefow windows]

I always use workspaces and this is so frustrating when I click on an windows, be move to another workspace and don't know which one it is.

Comment: See [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992558/how-can-i-configure-the-ubuntu-dock-to-show-windows-only-from-the-current-worksp), might be helpful for you. Not exactly what you're looking for, it's about hiding window-previews from other workspaces (so that you see previews of windows only from the current workspace).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the `Workspaces to Dock` GNOME Shell extension.

Drag the mouse pointer to the right side of the screen. A dock will slide out. In the dock, you can see what apps are running and where. And to move a window to another workspace, just drag the desired window from one workspace to another.

Find it at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/427/workspaces-to-dock/

Comment: Thanks you. I use this extension but this is not exactly what I need. Maybe there no solution to my question yet. Time to learn how to code gnome extension.