# Ubuntu 18.04 - get Ubuntu dock to only display the windows from the current screen (monitor)

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, dock

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 (with Linux kernel 4.15.0-33-generic) on a setup with laptop and an external monitor. Is there a way to make the dock in Ubuntu 18.04 only display the windows from the current **screen**. There was a similar feature in Ubuntu 16.04.

In short if an app is only opened on one of the screens it was still displayed in the launcher but with a different indicator. When there are two windows of an app (e.g. I have two gedits or two chromes opened) one for each screen, clicking on the icon in the dock opened the window for the corresponding screen (instead of displaying a picker with the two windows).

Is there a way to have similar configuration for Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Launch Terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-monitors true
```

Comment: where is this documented?

Comment: umm... right here?

Comment: Amazing this is not available in the settings .... works perfectly combined with
`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock multi-monitor true`
(Ubuntu 20.04 LTS / Gnome 3.36.x)

Comment: @math2001 According to [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992558/how-can-i-configure-the-ubuntu-dock-to-show-windows-only-from-the-current-worksp#comment2113711_992559), the gnome dock is a fork of Dash To Dock, which also does not really document this other than [here](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/blob/master/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock.gschema.xml#L203)

Answer (score 2):

You could also achieve the same by using the **dconf Editor** application (that can be found in Ubuntu store).
Just go to `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock` and search for `isolate-monitors` and toggle its value to make the change.