# How to set Application Switcher (Alt+Tab) to show apps from current monitor only on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, gnome-shell, application-switcher

Is there a way to only show apps on my current monitor when I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> on a dual monitor setup?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 - get Ubuntu dock to only display the windows from the current screen (monitor)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070001/ubuntu-18-04-get-ubuntu-dock-to-only-display-the-windows-from-the-current-scre)

Comment: @vanadium Nope. Doesn't work.

Comment: I could have know if I paid better attention: the alt tab switcher can be configured to work on the current workspace only, but not to work on the current monitor, unlike the dock. So I guess the answer to your question simply is a "No".

Answer (score 2):

This extension seems to work for me: [Current screen only on window switcher](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1437/current-screen-only-for-alternate-tab/)

According to the extension's [GitHub page](https://github.com/mmai/Current_screen_only_on_window_switcher):

> It filters the windows shown in the window switcher to those of the current monitor.
>
> You can enable it from its page on the Gnome extensions site: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1437/current-screen-only-for-alternate-tab/
>
> Or, to install manually :
>
> ```
> cd ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
> git clone https://github.com/mmai/Current_screen_only_on_window_switcher.git Current_screen_only_for_Alternate_Tab@bourcereau.fr
> ```
>
> ...and reload gnome shell :
>
> 1. Open the Run a Command dialog by pressing Alt+F2 on the keyboard.
> 2. Enter just r in the box and press Enter.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why this answer is so poor that it was a test on my mod queue? To me it genuinely 'looks ok' without having to actually try it.

Comment: i am disappointed by the fact that gnome needs an extension for every single small fart.