# [Ubuntu 20.04][Gnome 3.36.8] Configure multiple icons in the dock for multiple instances of the same application

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, icons, ubuntu-gnome

I have a multi-monitor setup and most of the times, I have multiple instances of an application (ex Chrome) open in different monitors. However, the number of icons of that application on the dock will still be one. Is there a way to configure it to show multiple icons on the doc for multiple instance of the running application?

In the below screenshot, I want the Chrome icon to appear twice - one for each instance and clicking on one of them should bring that instance of the application to the foreground in the same monitor that it was previously displaying in.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A disappointing answer may be more honest than no answer at all: no, a dock is not designed to work the way you want.

A dock, however, can be set to display [only the icons of applications running on that display](https://askubuntu.com/a/1070006/558158). That may be a second best option for you.