# Opening new windows of VSCode switches workspace

Tags: 20.04, workspaces

I'd like to have separate windows of VSCode open in different workspaces on my Ubuntu Desktop 20.04, using the Ubuntu dock. Generally the workflow is, if I want more than one coding project open at once, I create a new workspace and press Super+Shift+(vscode). However doing this will swap to the workspace where VScode is already open and then open a new instance.
I have not observed this with other apps.
If  it isn't clear, the desired behavior is for new windows (specifically vscode, currently only app doing this) to open in the current workspace.

While I'm here, I've tried the gsettings change [How can I configure the Ubuntu Dock to show windows only from the current workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992558/how-can-i-configure-the-ubuntu-dock-to-show-windows-only-from-the-current-works)
and it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an actual bug in vscode that will be fixed in next release: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/106727