# Key combination to switch between an application's windows in all of viewports

Tags: 14.04, unity, shortcut-keys, workspaces, application-switcher

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> is used to switch between an application's windows in the current viewport in Unity.

Is there another key combination to switch between an application's windows in all of viewports?

I do not want to change default behaviour of <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd>, which is  switching between an application's windows in the current viewport.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Unity.

Comment: By viewpoint do you mean Workspace?

Comment: @Tim see http://askubuntu.com/questions/44102/what-is-a-viewport-what-about-a-workspace

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inspired by Pineau's answer, I found a dirty trick to get it done: keep <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> for switching between application windows in one viewport, and (for example) <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to switch between application windows on all viewports.

Minor cosmetic downside is that the responsiveness is a little less accurate, since the settings need a fraction of a second to change. In Practice however, you will hardly notice.

1. install `xdotool`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Copy the following scipt into an empty file and save it as `switch.sh`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/alt-tab-bias-viewport false
   sleep 0.2
   xdotool keydown alt key 0x60
   dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/alt-tab-bias-viewport true
   sleep 1
   ```
3. set a key combination to run the script: `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts`. I choose <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, since it is close to the other one.

   Now you can use either <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to switch between all windows of (for example) gedit:

   [image]

   or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to switch between gedit windows of only the currect workspace:

   [image]

**note:**

1. In the script, the key above the <kbd>Tab</kbd> is set to `key 0x60`. This might be different on other lauyouts. In case it won't work, run in a terminal `xev`, then press <kbd>Return</kbd>, then the key above tab. In the output, look for a string like `(keysym 0x60, grave)`. The keysym value is the value you need in the (script-) line:

   ```
   xdotool keydown alt key 0x60
   ```
2. The values of `sleep 0.2` and `sleep 1` make the script work fine on my system, but they might be subject to optimization for faster systems (reduce).

**More options**

Similarly, you can set a key combination to switch between all *application windows* on *all viewports* the script would then be:

```
#!/bin/bash

dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/alt-tab-bias-viewport false
sleep 0.2
xdotool keydown alt key 0xff09
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/alt-tab-bias-viewport true
sleep 1
```

If you set for example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> for this, you have nice set of all options:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>  Switch between *current application's* windows on *current viewport*

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>  Switch between *current application's* windows on *all viewports*

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>  Switch between *all application* windows on *current viewport*

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>  Switch between *all application* windows on *all viewports*

[image]

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> : Switch between all application windows on *current viewport*

[image]

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>: Switch between all application windows on all viewports

Answer (score 6):

### **Generic solution using `wmctrl`**

---

**Overview**

The following script should be compatible with all [EWMH-compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Window_Manager_Hints) window managers (e.g. xfwm4, openbox, kwin, compiz...). It uses `wmctrl` and `xprop`, which can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install x11-utils wmctrl
```

**Installation**

Copy and save the following passage as `simple-window-switcher`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# based on a script by Robert Steiniger
# (http://lars.st0ne.at/blog/switch%20between%20windows%20within%20the%20same%20application)

Usage="
  Title:        simple-window-switcher 0.1
  Description:  switch between all windows of active application
  Author:       Copyright Glutanimate 2014 (https://github.com/Glutanimate)
  License:      GNU GPLv3
  Usage:        $(basename "$0") [-g|-l|-h]
                -g: global window switching (across all workspaces)
                -l: local window switching (current workspace)
                -h: display this help message

                If no argument is provided window switching will be set to global.
"

while getopts "lgh" OPTIONS; do
  case $OPTIONS in
    l ) Fields="3-4"
        ;;
    g ) Fields="4"
        ;;
    h ) echo "$Usage"
        exit 0
        ;;
   \? ) echo "$Usage"
        exit 1
        ;;
  esac
done

ActiveWinID="$(xprop -root | sed -n 's/_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW): window id # 0x//p')"
# fields 3-4: <desktop number> <window class>
ActiveWinClass="$(wmctrl -xl | grep "$ActiveWinID" | cut -d" " -f${Fields})"
WindowList="$(wmctrl -xl | grep "$ActiveWinClass" | cut -d" " -f1)"
NextWindow="$(echo "$WindowList" | grep -A1 "$ActiveWinID" | sed -n 2p)"

if [[ -z "$NextWindow" ]]; then
  NextWindow="$(echo $WindowList | head -n 1)"
fi

wmctrl -i -a "$NextWindow"
```

Mark the script as executable and save it anywhere you please (preferably in your PATH, e.g. `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin`).

**Usage**

Use they keyboard shortcuts menu of your window manager to assign `simple-window-switcher` to a hotkey of your choice. You can use the following parameters to control how the script behaves:

- `-g`: global window switching (across all workspaces)
- `-l`: local window switching (current workspace); might not work with Unity/Compiz (see comment section for further information)

Comment: Dear @Glutanimate, after `-l` also switches to windows on other workspaces.

Comment: @Kadir That's strange. It doesn't on my system. If you have some time, would you be willing to post the output of `wmctrl -xl` to a site like http://pastebin.com/ and link it here?

Comment: Dear @Glutanimate, here it is: http://pastebin.com/iJBAZ5a7

Comment: @Kadir Thanks! Looks like Unity/Compiz isn't exposing the workspace information properly so wmctrl has trouble picking it up (that's why you only see zeroes in the second column, those should be the workspace numbers). No idea if that's a bug or if it was designed that way. I didn't notice this because I was using LXDE. I'll add a note to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Open a Terminal and type the following command:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/alt-tab-bias-viewport false
```

Alternatively you can install the Unity Tweak Tool:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
unity-tweak-tool
```

Then enable the **Switch between windows on all workspaces** option in the Switcher Tab:

[image]

Comment: I want to preserve Alt-\`'s property, which is switching between an application's windows in the current viewport. I need another shortcut like Ctrl-Alt-\`, which will switch between an application's windows in all of the viewports.

Comment: @Kadir Unfortunately, the dconf property won't allow both config to coexist. It's one behaviour or the other.