# Desktop icon to application switcher

Tags: icons, 15.10, application-switcher

I would like to add an icon link in the Unity Launcher which opens the application switcher (the one that the keyboard shortcut alt+tab opens). How can I do this?

Edit:
I installed xdotools and have attempted make the desktop file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=gnome-panel-window-list
Name[en_US]=App Switcher
Exec=sh -c 'xdotool keydown Alt key Tab && sleep 4 && xdotool keyup Alt'
Name=App Switcher
Icon=gnome-panel-window-list
```

It almost works. The app launcher opens, however, I can't select the open windows.

Edit: 
The code above works. You just need to use the wheel on the mouse to switch :D

Comment: I have edited the question to clear up the confusion. I would like to have a click able icon in the unity launcher that opens the application switcher (the one that alt+tab opens).

Comment: Typically the launcher bar on the left side contains icons for all running applications. Is there a particular reason, why you don't want to use that? Your solution requires more mouse clicks and movement.

Comment: See comment below David's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could

1. [create an application launcher](/q/13758/175814) that
2. runs a command which [simulates a keyboard combination](/q/288114/175814).
3. You can then [use `gsettings` to add the launcher to the favourite list](/q/187381/175814).

Comment: Hi David, did you try? This was my first idea too, but it needs a physical key up to select the latest active/selected item. There is a clash of acting with the design of alt- tab here. The second time won't work.

Comment: No, I didn't try it since I don't have Unity conveniently available.

Comment: The same principle as here: http://askubuntu.com/a/517626/72216 I was wondering why it works there, but not in this case, until I realized the last selection is chosen by key release, not by clicking. That makes (an answer to) the question not work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Install mainmenu application: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/alacarte/

Then drag and drop your new launcher from the Unity dash to the Unity bar.

Comment: Search `alacarte` apps in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked through all the options. There isn't an option in alacarte  that opens the application switcher.

Comment: I think I do not understand what is the application switcher for you. Is it the Unity bar on the left ? Or the menu of ALT+TAB shortcut ?

Comment: The alt+tab one.

Comment: The icon is the same in both case. When you change the icon with alacarte you should see the same in the switcher. Maybe a unity log in/out is required.

Comment: I had proofread and edited my original post. (Sorry about that =_=;) What I meant was for an icon that opens the application switcher (the alt+tab one).