# What is exactly the relation between wmctrl -d and wmctrl -lG in Unity?

Tags: unity, command-line, workspaces, window-manager, wmctrl

from man wmctrl:

*wmctrl is a command that can be used to interact with an X Window manager that is compatible with the EWMH/NetWM specification. wmctrl can query the window manager for information, and it can request that certain window management actions be taken.*

#### The question specifically

The `wmctrl -d` command can be used to get information about desktops (viewports/workspaces), The `wmctrl -lG` command lists all windows, including their geometry information.

How can I (in Unity versus other window managers):

- get an overview of the workspaces and how they are arranged?
- find out which is the current workspace?
- find out where a window is located in an *absolute* sense?
- list windows that are on the current workspace?

from the command line, using these two commands?

#### Background information

---

*The wmctrl -d command* 
lists desktops. On (e.g.) Xubuntu, when I run `wmctrl -d`, I can clearly see in the output which is the current workspace, and the screen's resolution (DG) on the workspace(s).

```
0  - DG: 1024x600  VP: N/A  WA: 0,31 1024x569  1
1  - DG: 1024x600  VP: N/A  WA: 0,31 1024x569  2
2  - DG: 1024x600  VP: N/A  WA: 0,31 1024x569  3
3  * DG: 1024x600  VP: 0,0  WA: 0,31 1024x569  4
```

The current workspace is marked with a `*`.

On Unity however, the output of `wmctrl -d` shows only one (very large) workspace, marked with a `*`, no matter which is the current "workspace", e.g.:

```
0  * DG: 3360x2100  VP: 1680,0  WA: 65,24 1615x1026  N/A
```

---

*The wmctrl -lG command*
from `man wmctrl`:
`-l`:  *List the windows being managed by the window manager.*
`-G-`: *Include geometry information in the output of the -l action*

When I run `wmctrl -lG` on (e.g.) Xubuntu, with a mousepad window on each workspace:

```
0x03400003  0 241  197  533  244  jacob-1001PX Untitled 1 - Mousepad
0x03400197  1 299  222  533  244  jacob-1001PX Untitled 2 - Mousepad
0x034001be  2 236  201  533  244  jacob-1001PX Untitled 3 - Mousepad
0x034001e3  3 283  228  533  244  jacob-1001PX Untitled 4 - Mousepad
```

The information is quite understandable; from the second column, we know the workspace  the window is on, its position (x,y, column 3/4) and the size (x,y, column 5/6). The position is given in relation to the worspace it is located on.

On Unity however, it is quite a different story. When I have four workspaces and I open a gedit window on every one of them:

```
0x03c03b81  0 468  -884 875  741  jacob-System-Product-Name Niet-opgeslagen document 1 - gedit
0x03c03e74  0 369  164  1111 741  jacob-System-Product-Name Niet-opgeslagen document 2 - gedit
0x03c03f8e  0 -1269 214  1111 741  jacob-System-Product-Name Niet-opgeslagen document 3 - gedit
0x03c00085  0 -1376 -917 1111 741  jacob-System-Product-Name Niet-opgeslagen document 4 - gedit
```

Some windows have negative coordinates, some (may) have coordintates that exceed my screen's resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Viewports versus workspaces

As pointed out in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/44108/72216), there is an essential difference between Compiz/Unity and other window managers.

If we look at Xubuntu (XFCE), all workspaces are stand alone spaces. All we need to know is the workspace a window is on, and the x and y coordinates. Basically, there is no matrix in which the workspaces are ordered, apart from the "lineair" order 1, 2, 3 etc.

This is different in Unity, where there is actually only *one* workspace. The (spanning) workspace is divided in a number of sections, called viewports. These viewports are arranged in rows and columns.

That way it is possible that one window is partially visible on all viewports:

[image]

unlike workspaces:

[image]

#### Differences in the output of wmctrl -d and how to interpret

To understand the output of `wmctrl -lG`, we should understand its "anatomy":

[image]

1. desktop number (first = 0)
2. current desktop mark ("*" if it is the current desktop (workspace), "-" if not)
3. desktop geometry (the *size* of the desktop x-y)
4. viewport position (position on the desktop; *see Unity*)
5. workarea geometry as ("usable" size of the desktop, minus panels etc.; first column is px from left/top)
6. name of the desktop (possibly containing multiple spaces)

Since Unity only has one workspace, the output *always* shows a `*` on `[2]`. How do we know how the viewports are arranged and what is the current viewport?

The information is in `VP: 1680,0` (`[4]`). Not simply as a viewport number, but as an x and y coordinate. These coordinates can be zero or `x`*the screen's resolution. To know how the viewports are set up, we will need to know the screen's reolution as well (with the help of `xrandr`).

#### How to find out:

- how many viewports are there currently and how are they arranged:

  Looking at the `DG: 3360x2100` in the "Unity" example, and knowing that our screen's resolution is 1680x1050, we can conclude there are two columns of viewports (3360/1680) and two rows (2100/1050).
- which is the current workspace:

  *An example*
  The screen has a resolution of 1680x1050. The viewport information sais `VP: 1680,0`. Cordinates are displayed as the left upper corner, So we are on the second column, first row.
- where a window is located in an *absolute* sense:

  Once we know which viewport is the current one, we can localize the windows, looking at their coordinates in the output of `wmctrl -lG` `[3]`:

[image]

1. window - id
2. desktop number (on Unity: always 0 as pointed out)
3. window coordinates, from the perspective of the current viewport (x-y)
4. window size, from the perspective of the (w-h)
5. computer name
6. window name

   We can simply locate the window, with the origin at the left top of the current viewport.

   Below an example of a screen resolution of 1680x1050, viewports 2x2:

   *window coordinates from the perspective of viewport 1*

   [image]

   *window coordinates from the perspective of viewport 4*

   [image]

   - which are the windows on the current workspace:

   With the information above and the help of `wmctrl -lG` (the window coordinates, section `[3]`), quite simple:

   if

   1. a window's x-coordinate is between 0 and the screen's (horizontal) resolution, *and*
   2. a window's y-coordinate is between 0 and the screen's (vertical) resolution

   then a window is located on the current viewport.