# What are workspaces in Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome, workspaces

What are workspaces in Ubuntu?
What do these workspaces do exactly?
Is their any documentation I can refer to?

Comment: Not sure what your starting point is, but see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/44102/what-is-a-viewport-what-about-a-workspace

Comment: See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows.html)

Comment: tnx @DougSmythies